# Is there any way to utilize different Opportunity Layouts for differing accounts?

Tags: opportunity, page-layout

I need to create a new Opportunity layout and be able to toggle between these opportunities when a specific Account is used. For example, for Account Blue we would use the Blue Opportunity Layout, while for Account Red we use the Red Opportunity Layout. Is there any way to choose the layout while creating a New Opportunity or does the layout need to be pre-selected on the account itself? What would be the easiest way to build this out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to do this you would use RecordTypes

1. Create the record types for each of the differing account groups
2. Create page layouts to go with each record type
3. Create a WFR to set the record type based on your criteria
4. Assign the Page Layout to the appropriate profile and record type

This works well as long as you do not have a bazillion different record types

Comment: What about a bazillion-1 record types?

Comment: @sfdcfox - I would advise you determine if ***one*** could be removed or not at that point...

Comment: @Eric For #1, does that mean I need to create a unique Account Record Type, Opportunity Record Type and Case Record Type? Or can that one different Opportunity Record Type communicate with the standard Account and Case layouts?

Comment: You only need to worry about the Opportunity Record Types. Use a formula filed to pull the criteria needed to determine which opp record type to use and a WFR to set the record type based on the formula field value